# Python or SQL distinguish different types with different conditions

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is there anyway I could distinguish the number of different patterns using SQL statement. Here is the data:

[image]

Ttype = starts with T and includes at least one D (e.g: TDD/ TTDT/ TDT), it ends until next Q shows up.

Qtype = starts with Q and includes at least one D (e.g: QD/ QDDDQ/ QDQDQD), it ends until next T shows up.

I want to generate the number of Ttype (=2 in this case), the number of Qtype (=1), and their corresponding lengths of each type (how many T/D are included, say length of the Qtype in this case = 4). Is there anyway i could achieve this using sql statement with different conditions. Many thx!

I tried with the following codes and then subtract to get the difference. but then i got stuck. any help would be appreciated.

```
          select order from table ty where S like "T%"
          select order from table ty where S like "D"
```

Or is there anyway i could do this using Python?

Comment: You might want to wrangle this into an alternate format before doing string matching if that's an option. This could be really annoying to do with pure SQL in the structure you've got here.

Comment: How do you know where each type ends?

Comment: @shmosel  good question, sorry i did not mention this clearly, it ends until the other type shows up (e.g: for Ttype, it ends until one Q shows up, and vice versa).

Comment: So what's the first two rows?

Comment: @shmosel the first two are the names of columns, so column "S" and column "order". apologize again for not mentioning that clearly.

Comment: I was asking about the two rows after that. There's a T without a D and a Q without a D.

Comment: @shmosel those T and Q without D don't count. I only consider T /Q that are followed by D

Comment: If you can have random T's and Q's scattered throughout, there's again no way to know where one type ends and the next begins.

Comment: @shmosel  the first D will belong to the closest type, either Q or T. i guess i did not explain the whole question quite well.